# I creating a sanity project and suddenly, when I did ng serve I got this error:

Tags: javascript, database, cloud, backend, sanity

```
? Login type Google

Opening browser at https://api.sanity.io/v1/auth/login/google?type=token&label=Vidusha+%2F+Windows&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4321%2Fcallback

⠋ Waiting for browser login to complete... Press Ctrl + C to cancelError: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at baseOpen (C:\Users\Vidusha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sanity\cli\lib\_chunks\cli-icdWEj-T.js:13444:248) {        
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
Unhandled rejection: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at baseOpen (C:\Users\Vidusha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sanity\cli\lib\_chunks\cli-icdWEj-T.js:13444:248)
```

**login to Google and open the browser but I can't do it. and get the above error.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.